# Different syntax for if in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csh, tcsh

I am learning shell script and I find different syntax for shell script conditional statements. Does csh script have a different syntax than tcsh script. Some say

```
 if [ "$PASSWORD" == "$VALID_PASSWORD" ]; then
echo "You have access!"
 else
echo "ACCESS DENIED!"
  fi
```

some use

```
 if ($PASSWORD == $VALID_PASSWORD)
 echo "You have access!"
 else
echo "ACCESS DENIED!"
 endif
```

I tried my own and I get errors  like "if: Empty if" or "If: Expression Syntax" and these messages are very brief to understand. So I thought of asking how to sort out these issues and are there solutions different based on shell (csh, tcsh)

If my shell is tcsh, should I always tcsh script or can I write bash script.

Comment: As Carl's answer says, you can write scripts using whatever shell you like, regardless of what shell you use interactively. But read this: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Comment: Thanks Thompson .. I am just learning to program shells and I can learn bash shell than csh shell scripting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`csh` and `tcsh` share the same syntax for an `if` statement:

```
if (expr) then
...
else if (expr2) then
...
else
...
endif
```

Your other example is (probably) from `sh` or `bash`:

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
```

Where your list happens to be an invocation of the program (or sometimes shell builtin) `[`.

You can write scripts for whatever shell you want as long as you put the right one of

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/csh
#!/bin/tcsh
```

to match your script's intended shell at the top of the file.

Comment: The error I got for following code is "if : Empty if"

  











 if ( $1 == "one")
          echo "one"
        else if ($1 == "two")
           echo "two"
        else
            echo " no proper input"
        endif

when executed as ./script one

Comment: @Raghav that's because your `if` statement is missing its `then` keyword.

Comment: Thanks Gordon .. I did not know if and then should be in same line.. Now code is working

Comment: csh and tcsh also permit a limited single-line `if` statement: `if (expr) stmt` (distinguished by the lack of a `then`) -- but that form doesn't permit an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual script for that -

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is some secure program that uses security.

VALID_PASSWORD="secret" #this is our password.

echo "Please enter the password:"
read PASSWORD

if [ "$PASSWORD" == "$VALID_PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo "You have access!"
else
    echo "ACCESS DENIED!"
fi
```